# Group policy WMI Logon Server

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, wmi

I'm trying to setup a GP to do tasks if in a certain location, I believe the best way in doing this is a WMI filter. Could someone help me out? I've never used this part of GP before.

Was looking online and it seem that Win32_NetworkLoginProfile is the right method to detect what logon server they're using (which would indicate the location)?

Anyone have past experience in this

Answer (score 1):

Interesting idea. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get anything in the `LogonServer` property of the `Win32_NetworkLoginProfile` except `\\*`, which isn't very helpful. If it were me I might end up solving this with a logon script or scheduled task that parses the output from either `$Env:Logonserver` or `nltest /dsgetsite`. WMI Filters are mad slow anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Using the name of the server that processed the user's logon, no matter how you go about obtaining it, is probably a sub-optimal way of doing this.

If you're sure a certain Domain Controller is going to process their logon request it seems fairly likely that you've got that DC already situated in an Active Directory site. If that's the case, then you can just link a Group Policy Object to the site and be done with it.